# Problem with Errors (_rootHangleError, <anonymous closure, _microTaskLoop) in my flutter Dapp; is it because of walletconnect_dart pkg?

Tags: android, flutter, metamask, decentralized-applications, wallet-connect

The Code is as follows:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'package:walletconnect_dart/walletconnect_dart.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher_string.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  var connector = WalletConnect(
      bridge: 'https://bridge.walletconnect.org',
      clientMeta: const PeerMeta(
          name: 'My App',
          description: 'An app for converting pictures to NFT',
          url: 'https://walletconnect.org',
          icons: [
            'https://files.gitbook.com/v0/b/gitbook-legacy-files/o/spaces%2F-LJJeCjcLrr53DcT1Ml7%2Favatar.png?alt=media'
          ]));

  var _session, _uri, _signature;

  Future<void> loginUsingMetamask(BuildContext context) async {
    if (!connector.connected) {
      try {
        var session = await connector.createSession(onDisplayUri: (uri) async {
          _uri = uri;
          await launchUrl(Uri.parse(uri), mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
        });
        print(session.accounts[0]);
        print(session.chainId);
        setState(() {
          _session = session;
        });
      } catch (exp) {
        print(exp);
      }
    } 
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    connector.on(
        'connect',
        (session) => setState(
              () {
                _session = _session;
              },
            ));
    connector.on(
        'session_update',
        (payload) => setState(() {
              _session = payload;
              print(_session.accounts[0]);
              print(_session.chainId);
            }));
    connector.on(
        'disconnect',
        (payload) => setState(() {
              _session = null;
            }));
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Login Page")),
      body: Column(children: [
        ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              loginUsingMetamask(context);
            },
            child: Text("Connect to Metamask"))
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

I encounter the aforementioned errors when debugging in 'CallStack'; but the apk compiled version of the app runs fine except since ig the connector is not properly initialized the user is unable to get a popup on MetaMask to authorize the connection like this [Demo Image/Connection Auth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I43Us.png)

**Context**: I am trying to use **WalletConnect** protocol to integrate **Metamask** to my flutter dapp via deeplinking; this code works fine on all the tutorials I've watched but all of them ran on an IoS emulator; i wonder if there's something diff about android.

Any help would be appreciated; thnx!

[Screenshot of my errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pk4gV.png)